# What is this short function doing ? (_bird.physicsBody.velocity.dy < 0 ? 0.003 : 0.001)

Tags: objective-c

I was studying some code I noticed the following function.

Obviously, it is a short form of something, I have never come across this.

What does the **< 0 ? 0.003 : 0.001** do ? Can you explain in plain English? Thank you.

```
(_bird.physicsBody.velocity.dy < 0 ? 0.003 : 0.001)
```

Comment: If you are going to program in Objective-C and thus "C" (which is the base of Objective-C) you need to learn the language. There are many books and online references. Lookup "ternary" operator. Just like any other discipline you need to learn the tools.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
(_bird.physicsBody.velocity.dy < 0 ? 0.003 : 0.001)
```

is the same as:

```
if (_bird.physicsBody.velocity.dv < 0) {
    return 0.003;
} else {
    return 0.001;
}
```